# Extracting words based on a $ and unnesting the data

Tags: r

I am trying to do two things to my data. The data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
     grp newCol                                                                     
   <int> <chr>                                                                      
 1  6303 "The company sees earnings of $3.40 to $3.60 a share for all of 2008, agai…
 2  7686 "   -- reaffirmed its fiscal 2015 guidance of per share diluted earnings b…
 3  9577 "Analysts polled by FactSet anticipate earnings of 96 cents a share, down …
 4  6475 ""                                                                         
 5  5229 "The company also expects income to be \"significantly impacted\" by costs…
 6  2648 "Hoku also expects losses for the foreseeable future on significant cost i…
 7  3691 "St. Louis-based Emerson now sees full-year earnings of $2.40 to $2.60 a s…
 8  9297 ""                                                                         
 9  2080 "The restaurant group also raised its earnings guidance for fiscal 2007 to…
10  3513 "Guidance, For the full fiscal year 2008, the Company is moderating its pr…
```

I can run the following:

```
x <- d %>% 
  mutate(
    extractedWords = str_extract_all(newCol, "([^\\s]+\\s){2}earnings(\\s[^\\s]+){12}")
  )
```

Where I get:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   extractedWords
   <list>        
 1 <chr [1]>     
 2 <chr [3]>     
 3 <chr [1]>     
 4 <chr [0]>     
 5 <chr [0]>     
 6 <chr [0]>     
 7 <chr [1]>     
 8 <chr [0]>     
 9 <chr [2]>     
10 <chr [4]>
```

I firstly want to modify the `str_extract_all(newCol, "([^\\s]+\\s){2}earnings(\\s[^\\s]+){12}")` - which currently extracts the 2 words before the Word `earnings` and 12 words after the Word `earnings`. I want to change it such that it extracts the words before the dollar `$` symbol.

Secondly I want to `unnest` the columns. When I run:

```
x %>% 
  unnest(extractedWords)
```

The number of rows from the data goes from `10` to `12`. I want to `unnest` it but paste the `c("text", more text")` into something like `text, more text` or separated by `|` (or some variation).

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(grp = c(6303L, 7686L, 9577L, 6475L, 5229L, 2648L, 
3691L, 9297L, 2080L, 3513L), newCol = c("The company sees earnings of $3.40 to $3.60 a share for all of 2008, against $2.74 a share from continuing operations in 2007, an increase of 24% to 31%.   ", 
"   -- reaffirmed its fiscal 2015 guidance of per share diluted earnings between , We believe the guidance outlook for fiscal 2015 remains realistic and takes into consideration the heightened competitive market trends for the Diagnostics segment offset by strategic investments that target the growing outpatient segment and further growth of our Life Science segment through our focus on global expansion, increasing industrial market efforts, and emerging success in the AgriBio and genomics research areas., FISCAL 2015 GUIDANCE REAFFIRMED, For the fiscal year ending September 30, 2015, management expects net revenues to be in the range of $193 million to $200 million and per share diluted earnings to be between $0.85 and $0.91. The per share estimates assume an increase in average diluted shares outstanding from approximately 41.9 million at fiscal 2014 year end to approximately 42.4 million at fiscal 2015 year end. The revenue and earnings guidance provided in this press release is from expected internal growth and does not include the impact of any additional acquisitions the Company might complete during fiscal 2015.", 
"Analysts polled by FactSet anticipate earnings of 96 cents a share, down 10 cents from a year earlier. Revenue is expected to have decreased 5.5% to $30.4 billion, which would mark the fourth consecutive quarterly decline after six years of growth. Verizon has said it expects earnings and sales will be roughly flat this year.", 
"", "The company also expects income to be \"significantly impacted\" by costs related to its pending acquisition of SRS Labs Inc. (SRSL)., The company also expects income to be \"significantly impacted\" by costs related to its pending acquisition of SRS Labs Inc. (SRSL).", 
"Hoku also expects losses for the foreseeable future on significant cost increases.   ", 
"St. Louis-based Emerson now sees full-year earnings of $2.40 to $2.60 a share, down from its February forecast of $2.70 to $2.95 a share. The company also expects net sales for the fiscal year to fall 13% to 15% to $21 billion to $21.7 billion. Sales are expected to be hurt by about 5% because of currency translations, but boosted by 1% because of acquisitions.", 
"", "The restaurant group also raised its earnings guidance for fiscal 2007 to a range of $3.45 a share to $3.50 a share, and said its expects earnings for the third quarter ending in July of 85 cents to 89 cents a share and same-store sales growth of 5% to 6%.   ", 
"Guidance, For the full fiscal year 2008, the Company is moderating its previously issued guidance and expects net sales to be approximately $950 million and earnings per diluted share to be approximately $1.00, which includes approximately $0.45 per diluted share of restructuring charges and other unusual items. For the twelve months ended February 2, 2008, net sales were $1.09 billion and earnings per diluted share were $2.59., Set forth below is our reconciliation of net earnings per share, calculated in accordance with generally accepted accounting principles, or GAAP, to net earnings per share, as adjusted, for certain historical periods and certain future periods. For reference, we also include our previous guidance for third quarter fiscal 2008. Net earnings per share, as adjusted, excludes (i) the net impact of certain restructuring costs and other unusual items as well as the write off of unamortized financing costs during the first three quarters of fiscal 2008 and (ii) the anticipated impact of certain restructuring costs in the fourth quarter of fiscal 2008. We believe that investors often look at ongoing operations as a measure of assessing performance and as a basis for comparing past results against future results. Therefore, we believe that presenting our results and expected results excluding these items provides useful information to investors because this allows investors to make decisions based on our ongoing operations. We use the results excluding these items to discuss our business with investment institutions, our board of directors and others. Further, we believe that presenting our results and expected results excluding these items provides useful information to investors because this allows investors to compare our results and our expected results for the periods presented to other periods.,                           Guidance   Results      for      Guidance   Guidance"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: "I want to change it such that it extracts the words before the dollar $ symbol"--which, and/or how many, words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean with the first part of your question. Assuming you want to extract all words after the word `earnings` and before `$`, this should do what you want. It uses a 'positive lookahead' and allows for *any* number of words until it finds the *first* dollar sign (hence the `*?`).

Rather than `unnest`ing, I loop over the `extractedWords` column using `purrr::map_chr`, which returns a character vector, which makes further unnesting unneccessary.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  mutate(
    extractedWords = str_extract_all(newCol, "([^\\s]+\\s){2}\\$(\\s?[^\\s]+){12}")
  ) %>% 
  mutate(result = map_chr(extractedWords, str_c, "", collapse="|"))
```

EDIT: edited the regular expression to extract 2 words before the dollar sign and 12 words after it. Note I had to escape the dollar sign (`\\$`) for it to work, since a dollar sign has a special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks! actually what I want is to replace `earnings` with the `$` sign. That is, extract the two words before the `$` and the `12` words after the `$`.

Comment: I get this error `Error: Result 4 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0`

Comment: See new edit: this should work. It replaces the empty character vectors with an empty string.